# How to require inside a Racket macro?

Tags: racket, metaprogramming

I currently am putting unit tests at the bottom of the file I'm working on, like this:

```lisp
(provide foo)
(define (bar x) (+ 1 x))

;; unit tests
(module+ test
  (require racket/pretty)
  (define testcases '(2 3 4))
  (for ([test testcases])
    (pretty-print (bar test))))
```

This works, but I want to avoid repeating the boilerplate unit test code for all my modules.  Having never written a macro in Racket before, I'm unsure how to get the various parts to fit together.

I would like to have the following code expand to the boilerplate version above:

```lisp
(provide foo)
(define (bar x) (+ 1 x))

;; unit tests
(test foo '(2 3 4))
```

Answer (score 4):

For the `test` macro, are you sure you need to generate a `require` from the macro? You can have the `test` macro generate a use of `pretty-print` if `racket/pretty` is required in the file that defines `test`, and then it doesn't matter whether there's a require in the file that uses `test`.

For example if you have two files `macro.rkt` and `use.rkt`:

**<sub>file `macro.rkt`:</sub>**

```
#lang racket
(provide test)
(require racket/pretty
         syntax/parse/define)

(define-simple-macro (test fn:id args:expr)
  (module+ test
    (define testcases args)
    (for ([test testcases])
      (pretty-print (fn test)))))
```

**<sub>file `use.rkt`:</sub>**

```
#lang racket
(require "macro.rkt")
(provide foo)
(define (foo x) (+ 1 x))

;; unit tests
(test foo '(2 3 4))
```

Then the reference to `pretty-print` works in the output of the macro even though it's not normally available in `use.rkt`. It works because `pretty-print` gets its scope from the macro definition site, not the use site.

Does this work for your problem?

Comment: If I can generate the `require` that would be ideal.  One reason (that I didn't mention) for putting the require inside the `(module+ test ...` is that it seems to reduce compile times.